# Mapping a dictionary to a hibernate-mapping with C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, hibernate-mapping

I got following C# class:

```
public class SomeClass()
{
   public SomeClass()
   public Guid Id;
   public virtual Dictionary<string,int> DictionaryInClass;
   public virtual string Description;

}
```

In hibernate mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="..."
                   namespace="...">
  <class name="SomeClass" abstract="true" table="SomeClass">
 <property name="Id" />
 <property name="Description" />
 <map> or <list>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

should I use set or map? and how exactly? something like this but I get errors on not having right kind of properties and elements, if trying to use composite-element it complains on not having class for "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary".

```
<map name="DictionaryInClass" table="SomeClass_separateTableForDict">
  <key column="SomeClassId" not-null="true" />
   <index column="key" /> <!-- should there be index? -->
   <property="value" /> <!-- kinda lost here -->
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with following solution:

```
<map name="DictionaryInClass" table="SomeClass_separateTableForDict">
   <key column="SomeClassId" /> <!-- This is the key to SomeClass -->
   <map-key column="key_column" /> <!-- This is the key in the dictionary with type string -->
   <element="value_column" /> <!-- This is the value in the dictionary -->
</map>
```

This solution also required to change dictionary to IDictionary in c#-class.